# GCC diverent result between -O0 and -O2 (in GCC version < 9.x same result)

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a simple C++ application.
The application makes now sense (I remove very much, to have a simple sample).

I found out:

- Application have different behavior between compiling -O0 and -O2 (GCC version < 9.x)
- A simple std::cout (should not change the application behavior) CHANGE the behavior.
  With this output the application do the same with -O0 and -O2.
- With GCC 8.X, 7.X.... there is no different between -O0 and -O2

Gotbold [Link](https://godbolt.org/z/45E9z5c6P) to the Code:

```
int release(char** pPointer1, char** pPointer2) {

    (pPointer1[0])--;

    std::cout << "Test: " << (char*)pPointer1[0] << std::endl; // <- With this line -O2 and -O0 do the same

    if (pPointer1[0] == 0) {
        std::cout << " pPointer1[0] " << (char*)(pPointer1[0]) << std::endl;
        return 12;
    } else {
        std::cout << "false (pPointer1[0] == 0) " << (pPointer1[0] == 0) << std::endl;
        return 13;
    }
}


int main() {
    char* pList1[3];
    char* pList2[3];

    pList1[0] = (char*)1;

    return release(pList1, pList2);
}
```

I know, it is not a good code. Bit should the compiler do the same with -O2 and -O0.
And why the  `std::cout`  line change the behavior?

Thanks all

Comment: Did you add only one `cout` or all of them? If you remove all of them, then the optimizer can discard the whole funciton and calculate the final result without calling it.

Comment: I"m pretty sure `pList1[0]--` is undefined behavior since `pList1[0]` is a `char*` but it's not actually pointing to an array, meaning that trying to decrement it doesn't have any well-defined meaning. Since your program is exhibiting UB, anything can happen, meaning there's no reason to think that its output will be consistent across varying compiler versions, optimization settings, or even runs of the same compiled binary multiple times.

Comment: And passing that invalid `char *` to `ostream::operator<<` is even more UB.

Comment: Just because a pointer `pFoo` is defined doesn't mean that `pFoo--` is valid. Pointer arithmetic is valid for going up and down arrays, but `pList[0]` isn't pointing to _any_ valid memory location, much less the middle of a `char[]` array.

Comment: Ptr[0] pointds to `1` so it is a valid pointer and should be valid to decrease it.

Comment: I change only the ONE cout line to change the behavior

Comment: @Devolus `pList1[0]` doesn't point to `1`. `pList1[0] = (char*)1;` is setting the _value of_ `pList[0]` to `1`, not to the address of a location in memory where `1` is stored. And even if asker had written `char someChar = 1; pList[0] = &someChar;`, it would _still_ be undefined behavior to decrement `pList[0]`.

Comment: Can you please explain exactly which version of g++ shows the different behavior, and what that behavior actually is in each case?  On all the versions I tried on godbolt, using either `-O0` or `-O2` the program prints `Test:` and returns 12.  I wasn't able to reproduce any different behavior.

Comment: Follow the link, Compiler ist "x86-64 GCC 9.1". Commend out the line maked with "With this line....". Than with O2 the return value is 13. With O0 the reutn value is 12. Change the GCC version to 8.3. Than the return value is 12 every time.

Comment: Oh, I see it now.  Okay, so there are two different directions you can take this question.  As Nathan says, your code has undefined behavior so in principle a compiler can do whatever it likes, and it's totally normal in such a case that behavior will vary with optimization options.  So option (1) would be to ask why your code does have UB; you'll get "language lawyer" answers with pointers to relevant sections of the C++ standard. [...]

Comment: Option (2) would be to ask why this particular compiler/library/architecture/OS combination, with these particular optimization options, produces these two specific behaviors for your broken code.  You'll get answers discussing the internal implementation of the compiler and library, perhaps expecting you to interpret the assembly code that it generates.  So, please clarify your question and state which type of answer you are looking for.  If you want both then it would be better to split this into two separate questions.

Comment: @NathanPierson: At the very least, the C++ standard certainly doesn't promise that there exists any pointer value which, when decremented, equals a null pointer.  (In particular there is no guarantee that `(char *)1` has this property.)  So there is no guarantee that the test `pPointer1[0] == 0` can ever be true, so the compiler is at liberty to assume it is always false and optimize out that branch of the `if`.